# "Store" objects during mapping with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Let's say, we have two source types for mapping, and one destination:

```
class TSource
{
    public float A { get; set; }
    public float B { get; set; }
}

class TSupport
{
    public float C { get; set; }
    public float D { get; set; }
}

class TDestination
{
    public float A { get; set; }
    public float B { get; set; }
    public float C { get; set; }
    public float D { get; set; }
}
```

And instance of TSupport is obtained with some method, using TSource instance:

```
private TSupport GetSupportInstance(TSource source)
```

So, usually, I'd do this with double mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
Mapper.CreateMap<TSupport, TDestination>();
//...
var support = GetSupportInstance(source);

var destination = Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source);
Mapper.Map(support, destination);
```

This also may be done in single mapping using manual resolve:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()
    .ForMember(desc => desc.C, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src =>
    {
        var support = GetSupportInstance(src);
        return support.C;
    }))
    .ForMember(desc => desc.D, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src =>
    {
        var support = GetSupportInstance(src);
        return support.D;
    }));
```

As you can see, I'm using GetSupportInstance twice, for each property. So, finally, my question is - is it possible to obtain support in mapping once, store it somehow, and reuse it in mappings for different properties?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()
    .ForMember(d => d.C, x => x.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.D, x => x.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dst) => {
        var support = GetSupportInstance(src);
        dst.C = support.C;
        dst.D = support.D;
    });
```

Comment: Will this comply with property checks of `AssertConfigurationIsValid`?

Comment: Well, you could `Ignore()` properties `C` and `D` and then `AssertConfigurationIsValid` passes.

Comment: Then this makes no sense for me. I want to handle this all in one mapping to ensure, that is covers all properties of `TDestination`, using `AssertConfigurationIsValid`. If I had no such need, I'd better use double map as easiest way with smallest line usage. Thanks for input anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go about using a custom resolver that caches the instance you need. It would look something like this.

```
public class MySupportInstanceResolver : ValueResolver<TSource, TDestination> 
{
    private static readonly ISupportInstance _supportInstance;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MySupportInstanceResolver ()
    {
      _supportInstance=GetSupportInstance();
    }

    protected override string ResolveCore(Journal source)
    {
        return _supportInstance;
    }
}
```

Then you could use it as:

```
 cfg.CreateMap<TSource, Tdest>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.C, 
            opt => opt.ResolveUsing<MySupportInstanceResolver>().FromMember(name => name.C));
});
```